# How do I dereference this hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

sub giveMeARef {
    my %hash = %{$_[0]};

    print "arg: ", Dumper($_[0]);
    print "deref: ", Dumper(%hash);
}

my %hash = ( "a" => (1,2,3), "b" => (3,4,5));

giveMeARef(\%hash);
```

This produces the following output:

```
arg: $VAR1 = {
          '2' => 3,
          '4' => 5,
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 3
        };
deref: $VAR1 = 'b';
$VAR2 = 3;
$VAR3 = '2';
$VAR4 = 3;
$VAR5 = 'a';
$VAR6 = 1;
$VAR7 = '4';
$VAR8 = 5;
```

I tried to follow the examples in [How do I dereference a Perl hash reference that's been passed to a subroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282987/how-do-i-dereference-a-perl-hash-reference-thats-been-passed-to-a-subroutine)

But I believe because my hash is more complicated, it isn't working out for me. How do I get back to the original structure I passed in?

Comment: You're flattening your lists upon creation. You need to use references instead: `(a => [1, 2, 3], b => [3, 4, 5])`.

Comment: Note that your `giveMeARef` is extremely wasteful. It should be: `sub giveMeARef {
    my $hash = $_[0];
    pop(@{ $hash->{a} });
}`

Comment: What do you intend to do? Just print the array or access its elements?

Comment: @ikegami What do you mean by wasteful?

Comment: Unnecessarily copying the hash is a waste of time and memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511461/how-do-i-dereference-this-hash-in-perl#comment54806600_33511461), you're flattening a list when you create `%hash`. The fat comma (`=>`) is a synonym for the comma that causes barewords on the left to be interpreted as strings, but it doesn't matter in this case because you've already got a string on the left. In effect, your hash assignment really looks like this:

```
my %hash = ("a", 1, 2, 3, "b", 3, 4, 5);
```

It looks like you were trying to assign arrays to `a` and `b`, but in Perl, hash values are always scalars, so you need to use references to anonymous arrays instead:

```
my %hash = (a => [1, 2, 3], b => [3, 4, 5]);
```

It's also worth noting that your subroutine is making a shallow copy of the hash reference you pass in, which may have unintended/unforeseen consequences. Consider the following:

```
use Data::Dump;

sub giveMeARef {
    my %hash = %{$_[0]};
    pop(@{$hash{a}});
}

my %hash = (a => [1, 2, 3], b => [3, 4, 5]);

dd(\%hash);
giveMeARef(\%hash);
dd(\%hash);
```

Which outputs:

```
{ a => [1, 2, 3], b => [3, 4, 5] }
{ a => [1, 2], b => [3, 4, 5] }
```

Comment: Good point about better not making a copy of the referenced hash.

Answer (score 3):

The code is fine, but your test hash is not what you think it is.

You cannot construct a hash like that. The lists in there got flattened out. You need to use array-refs instead:

```
my %hash = ( "a" => [1,2,3], "b" => [3,4,5]);
```

Since you are going to take a reference to that hash anyway, you might as well start there:

```
my $hash_ref = { a => [1,2,3], b => [3,4,5] };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

- The way Dumper is used to print the hash without passing reference wherein it resolves to print all the elements as $VAR1, $VAR2, etc.

  Dumper(\%hash)
- The way the hash is initialized. Since the value is a list, it should be initialized as

  my %hash = ( "a" => [1,2,3], "b" => [3,4,5]);

A more correct code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

sub giveMeARef {
    my %hash = %{$_[0]};

    print "arg: ", Dumper($_[0]); #Dumper is passed a Ref.
    print "deref: ", Dumper(\%hash); # Dumper should be called with a hash ref.
}

my %hash = ( "a" => [1,2,3], "b" => [3,4,5]);

giveMeARef(\%hash);
```